# js regexp '|' matches when either side matchs

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match string that is either "/ab/" or "/anything except '/'"; I thought it can easily be done with a '|'. But I didn't get the result I want:

```
console.log(/"(\/ab\/)"/.test('"/ad/"')); // false
console.log(/"(\/[^\/]*)"/.test('"/ad/"')) // false
console.log(/"(\/ab\/)|(\/[^\/]*)"/.test('"/ad/"')); //true
```

Did I misunderstood something?

Comment: Why are you testing your string containing `ad` against `ab`? Is that a typo?

Comment: Replace `)|(` with `|`, you did not build the alternation group correctly (you have two instead of one).

Comment: `console.log(/"(\/ab\/|\/[^\/]*)"/.test('"/ad/"')`

Comment: @GlasG Nope. I just need a random a string that should not match. Apparently it was not that random.

Comment: I'm finding it a little hard to understand your problem, because of the confusing characters (strings containing `/` and `'`, in conjunction with a regex, will always be a bit confusing!). It might help to provide a simple set of strings that you expect to match/not match, as part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternation applies to *everything* prior and after it, including the `"`s. You were saying "match `"(\/ab\/)` or `\/[^\/]*)"`".
. To avoid that, put the alternation in a group of its own (rather than between two groups): `/"(\/ab\/|\/[^\/]*)"/`

```js
console.log(/"(\/ab\/)"/.test('"/ad/"')); // false
console.log(/"(\/[^\/]*)"/.test('"/ad/"')) // false
var rex = /"(\/ab\/|\/[^\/]*)"/;
console.log(rex.test('"/ad/"')); //now false
console.log(rex.test('"/ab/"')); //true
console.log(rex.test('"/an"')); //true
```